# In how many ways can we say "go straight ahead"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, synonyms, direction-complement

I have heard 一直走(*Yīzhí*) and 往前(*wǎng qián*)走, but it seems the online translators prefer 一直往前走(*Yīzhí wǎng qián zǒu*) or 一直向(*xiàng*)前走 (if we're going forward)...

From the above which are the most commonly used and in which contexts? And how many other ways can we get the same meaning (even replacing 走 by other verb)?

Comment: 一直往前走 (written) and 一直向前走 (oral, thou acceptable as written) are both commonly used.

Comment: Sichuanese has 拉伸(cen)走 for "go straight ahead" and 抵拢 for "go to the end" esp. famous for 抵拢倒拐

Answer (score 2, accepted):

一直走 / 往前走 / 一直往前走 / 一直向前走

`Q1) From the above which are the most commonly used and in which contexts?`

一直走 = keep walking

往前走 = walk straight

一直往前走 = keep walking straight

一直向前走 = keep walking straight

Any of the above is understandable if your context is to help people with direction. Note that 一直走 / 往前走 are a bit short and lack a bit of politeness.

`Q2) how many other ways can we get the same meaning (even replacing 走 by other verb)?`

直走

向前走

In case of car, replace 走 by 开 (short hand for 开车 [Driving]）

一直开

往前开

一直往前开

一直向前开

In case of bicycle, replace 走 by 骑 （short hand for 骑车）

一直骑

往前骑

一直往前骑

一直向前骑